# program for determining price is giving wrong answer

Tags: python

Please pardon any mistakes in formatting, I am not used to using stack overflow.

So basically I have this problem to solve:

> A bagel shop charges 75 cents per bagel for orders of less than
> a half-dozen bagels and 60 cents per bagel for orders of a half-dozen or more. write a program that requests the number of bagels ordered and displays the total cost

and the code that I have written for it:

```
if bagels<=6:
    total=bagels*.75
    print(total)
elif bagels>6:
    bagels=bagels-5
    total=bagels*.60+(5*.75)
    print(total)
```

the example given for a correct program would give the price at 7.20, but my program is giving 7.95.  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value bagels you input to get 7.20?

Comment: 1. You need `<` and `>=` instead of `<=` and `>`. 2. The problem doesn't say that the first half dozen bagels are at a higher price, so in the second case you need to just multiply the total number of bagels by 0.60.

Comment: It would seem you are making this too complicated by calculating a marginal cost of bagels. An order of 12 bagels should just be `12 * 0.60` which is `7.20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
bagels=12
if bagels<6:
    total=bagels*.75
    print(total)
elif bagels>=6:
    total=bagels*.60
    print(total)
```